# Metódo Incluir - MVC - trabalhando com inserção de dados em duas tabelas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-api

Eu tenho duas classes:

- **Usuario**
- **UsuarioP**

onde `Usuario` possui seu `id` (PK) e `UsuarioP` possui o `id` (FK) de `Usuario`.

Estou trabalhando no ASP.NET MVC 4 usando Fluent API.

As classes são mapeadas dentro do projeto para fazer conexão com o banco. Meu projeto é dividido em *controllers*, *services*, *models* e *views*.

Tenho uma tela `Usuario` que usa 1 campo de `UsuárioP`.

1) Como posso instanciá-la na classe sem ser da maneira abaixo? (dessa forma não funciona por conta do relacionamento, do contrário funcionaria):

**Classe Usuario.cs**

```
public string login { get { return this.UsuarioP.login; } set { login = value; } }
```

2) Na tela de inclusão, ao adicionar os items de `Usuario`, eu também deveria mudar o status da tela, esse status está dentro de `UsuarioP`.

**Controller**

```
        public ViewResultBase Incluir(Usuario model)
        {
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {

                    this.Service.SalvaUsuarioP(model);
                    return this.SuccessView(true);
                }
                catch (ValidationException exception)
                {
                    base.AddValidationErrors(exception);
                    return base.PartialView(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.PartialView(model);
            }
        }
```

**Service**

```
        public void SalvaUsuarioP(Usuario item)
        {
            //Salva os campos de Usuario(está funcionando perfeitamente)
            base.context.Usuario.Add(item);

            //Tentativa para salvar o login e o seu estado em UsuarioP
            foreach (var usuarioP in base.context.UsuariosP.Where(x => x.IdUsuario == item.Id))
            {
                item.login = usuarioP.Login;
                usuarioP.TipoParticipante = 3;
                base.context.UsuariosP.Add(usuarioP);
            }

        }
```

Já tentei dessa forma, mas não consegui. No caso, o `item.login` só está funcionando pelo fato de login estar como `[NotMapped]` em `Usuario.cs`.

Resumindo: Na tela de inclusão (`Usuario`) tenho um campo que deveria trazer de (`UsuarioP`), o login.

Na hora de acionar o metódo de inclusão, ele deveria salvar os campos do `Usuario` e salvar o login em `UsuarioP` usando `IdUsuario` como chave e também alterando o status do login (`TipoParticipante = 3`).

**Os erros que já obtive**

```
Invalid columm login (porque realmente `login` não existem em `Usuario`)
```

Na hora de debugar ele inclui somente os campos do `Usuario`, e nem mesmo passa pelo `foreach`.

Não sei como fazer funcionar, podem me ajudar? E se eu não tiver sendo claro, eu coloco mais detalhes.

Answer (score 3):

Antes de mais nada é importante saber que [`Usuario` tem cardinalidade 1 para N com `UsuarioP`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89380/d%c3%bavidas-sobre-relacionamento-com-fluent-api-para-o-ef-5?lq=1), senão é impossível responder a esta pergunta.

> 1) Como posso instancia-la na classe sem ser da maneira abaixo?

```
public string login {get { return this.UsuarioP.login} set { login = value} }
```

De fato, isto aqui não vai funcionar porque a cardinalidade é 1 para N, ou seja, você teria que definir qual dos N `Login`s você estaria alterando.

> 2) Na tela de inclusão ao adicionar os items de Usuário, eu também deveria mudar o status da tela, esse status está dentro de UsuarioP.

Pelo mesmo motivo, esta parte do código do serviço está errada, e por mais motivos:

```
        //Tentativa para salvar o login e o seu estado em UsuarioP
        foreach (var usuarioP in base.context.UsuariosP.Where(x => x.IdUsuario == item.Id))
        {
            item.login = usuarioP.Login;
            usuarioP.TipoParticipante = 3;
            base.context.UsuariosP.Add(usuarioP);
        }
```

Não faz o menor sentido você selecionar vários `UsuarioP`, depois atribuir `Login` pra ele mesmo. Acho que há uma grande confusão de conceitos aí.

Se você quer mudar o status do `UsuarioP`, o código abaixo resolve:

```
        foreach (var usuarioP in item)
        {
            usuarioP.TipoParticipante = 3;
            base.context.Entry(usuarioP).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

Ou ainda, se o registro é novo:

```
        foreach (var usuarioP in item)
        {
            usuarioP.TipoParticipante = 3;
            base.context.UsuariosP.Add(usuarioP);
        }
```

Ou melhor ainda, você pode definir o tipo *default* no construtor:

```
public UsuarioP() {
    TipoParticipante = 3;
}
```

Não use a classe relacionada para fazer atribuições até que os conceitos sobre como trabalhar com o Entity Framework estejam devidamente fixados.

Comment: Mas para cada usuário adicionado eu preciso adicionar um UsuarioP com o status TipoParticipante = 3. base.context.Entry(usuarioP).State = EntityState.Modified; eu consigo ?

Comment: Você está adicionando, não editando. `EntityState.Modified` é só para edição.