# Dúvidas sobre relacionamento com Fluent API para o EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-api

Tenho duas classes:

- **Usuario** > Contem sua PK (ID).
- **UsuarioP** > Contem o ID(FK) de usuário.

**Class Usuário.cs**

```
public Usuario()
{
    this.UsuariosP = new List<UsuarioP>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }

(...)
public virtual ICollection<UsuarioP> UsuariosP { get; set; }
```

**Class UsuarioP.cs**

```
public partial class UsuarioP
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdUsuario{ get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }
    (...)

    public virtual Usuario Usuario{ get; set; }
}
```

As classes foram mapeadas assim.

Eu gostaria de chamar o `Login` que está dentro de `UsuárioP` em `Usuario`. Não consigo por causa do relacionamento das duas, do contrário eu conseguiria.

**Tentativas**
- Já criei um atributo virtual de UsuarioP dentro de Usuario. (Sem sucesso)
- Já tentei instancia-lo dessa maneira:

```
public string login {get { return this.UsuarioP.Login} } (Sem sucesso)
```

- Colocando `Login` em `Usuario.cs` como `[NotMapped]` (Sem sucesso)

**Importante:** Quero fazer o get e set desse atributo. Meu projeto está trabalhando com *controllers*, *services*, *models* e *views*.

Como chamar o `Login` dentro de `UsuarioP`, para que eu possa usá-lo nas telas de Usuário?

Obs.: Trabalhando com MVC 4
      EF 5
      Fluent API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com seu código. O mapeamento está perfeito. Há, sim, algo de errado na maneira com que você está usando.

`Usuario` tem N `UsuarioP` (cardinalidade 1 para N). Ou seja, você terá também N `Login`s, sendo um para para `UsuarioP`.

Você quer implementar o `get` e `set` de `Login`, mas eles já estão implementados de forma automática:

```
public string Login { get; set; }
```

O Entity Framework se encarrega de carregar as informações pra você no momento em que elas são utilizadas. Possivelmente você está utilizando `Login` da forma incorreta. Vou dar alguns exemplos de como você pode estar recuperando esse `Login`.

## 1. Iterando sobre a coleção `UsuariosP`

Sua *View* pode fazer o seguinte:

```
@foreach (var usuarioP in Model.UsuariosP)
{
    <div>@usuarioP.Login</div>
}
```

## 2. Localizando um registro em específico

Também na *View*:

```
<div>@Model.UsuariosP.First().Login</div>
@{
    var teste = @Model.UsuariosP.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == 2);
}
@if (teste != null) {
    <div>@teste.Login</div>
}
```

Comment: Eu deveria usar um template dentro do atributo de login. Essa forma que vc fez a 1) .. eu conseguiria colocar o template?

Comment: Sim, mas isso é outra pergunta. Pode fazer e colar o link aqui que eu respondo ela pra você.

Comment: Eu fiz uma pergunta ontem sobre isso.. partindo que a idéia inicial era como fazer o get desse atributo, não obtive ajuda: pq na verdade o que eu preciso mesmo é  disso (estou totalmente perdido) :http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89318/met%C3%B3do-incluir-mvc-trabalhando-com-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dados-em-duas-tabelas

Comment: Eu queria usar o get desse atributo e fazer com que na hora de inserir na tela inclusão ele recebe o valor para a outra tabela...

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente seu contexto está configurado com o [LazyLoading (Carregamento preguiçoso)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/dd456846%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) habilitado. O LazyLoading é utilizado para que o carregamento das entidades relacionadas seja realizado apenas quando chamamos a propriedade mapeada. No caso de MVC isso não funciona, pois o acesso à informação é realizado na camada do cliente, portanto este carregamento deve ser desativado.

Segundo a [documentação do ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) além deste problema o carregamento preguiçoso pode causar uma lentidão no carregamento das informações, visto que o numero de requisições pode ser maior do que o normal para que a serialização seja realizada corretamente.